# OpenGL 4.1 on Macbook Air

Tags: drivers, graphics, macbook, opengl, mesa

I'm trying to get OpenGL 4.1 running on a Mid-2012 Macbook Air dual booting Ubuntu. According to [this website](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook-air/specs/macbook-air-core-i5-1.7-11-mid-2012-specs.html), I have Intel 4000 HD Integrated Graphics, which according to [this site](https://people.freedesktop.org/~imirkin/glxinfo/) should provide full support for OpenGL 4.2, but OpenGL 4.1 has only partial support? [This site](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202823) indicates that this computer should be able to run OpenGL 4.1 (albeit on MacOS and not Ubuntu). `GLXInfo | grep version` provides the following output:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ glxinfo | grep version
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
    Max core profile version: 3.3
    Max compat profile version: 3.0
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.0
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 17.0.1 - padoka PPA
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 17.0.1 - padoka PPA
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 17.0.1 - padoka PPA
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
```

indicating that while Mesa is up to date at version 17, OpenGL is only at version 3.3. I've been working on this for hours, and I'd appreciate any help I can get (or maybe I just need someone to tell me it's impossible). Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.